# Why the APK crash when I open it

Tags: android, android-studio

I can not open the APK normally, but the debugger has no serious problems. I consider that the problem may occur in here.

**MainActivity.java**:

```java
private TextView text;
public static Toast toast = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setText("IP address : "+getLocalHostIp());

    new ServerListener().start();
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: show the logcat also to able see the error

Comment: from the code you posted m do you want to get the IP address of the device?

Comment: yeah, i want to get the IP address

Comment: @陳毓凱 Welcome to SO. The preferred way of saying "thanks" around here is to Upvote helpful answers and Accept the one that fixed your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong id for textView in your code which is causing the app to crash.

You've defined `setText` as id for the TextView in your .xml file `android:id="@+id/setText"`,  and you are using "`text`" as the id to map the TextView in your code `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);`, which obviously can not be found and is the cause of the problem.

to solve this, do one of the following:

1. Change  `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);` to  `text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.setText);`
2. or change `android:id="@+id/setText"` to `android:id="@+id/text"`

Answer (score 0):

Your id for TextView is wrong, you can use below code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```